# Какая база данных лучше всего подойдет для хранения файлов?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, nosql

У меня есть потребность в хранении файлов в базе данных, это не обязательно SQL база, можно и какая нибудь другая. У меня файлы от нескольких килобайт до нескольких десятков мегабайт и они все связаны с id, файлов таких миллионы. Индексировать содержимое файлов не требуется. Какая база данных лучше всего подойдет для хранения такого типа данных? Мне важна производительность.

Использовать базу буду через Java приложение, хочу получить примерно такое DAO:

```java
public interface FileDao {

    void saveFile(int id, File src);

    void loadFile(int id, File desc);

}
```

Comment: Родную файловую систему никак нельзя?

Comment: @avp нельзя. доступ к базе нужен удаленный, и одновременно с разных хостов и java-приложений соответственно

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что вам нужен Google Cloud Storage или что-то подобное

Comment: Что мешает серверу, с которым соединяются для обмена файлами java-приложения с разных хостов, использовать локальную файловую систему для хранения этих файлов?

Comment: @avp ничего не мешает. но я ищу готовое решение, с авторизацией, с транзанкциями, с документацией..

Comment: @Anatoly Google Cloud Storage, полагаю, денег стоит, а мне бы на свой хост что-то поставить и пользоваться

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук, если готовое решение, то можно посмотреть на [FTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP) или его аналоги

Comment: Что мешает хранить файлы полями-блобами в любой серверной базе? В том же PostgreSQL?

Comment: @cauf не знаю, а оно будет нормально работать? файлы могут быть по несколько десятков мегабайт. и как мне sql запросами отправлять такие объемы, не хотелось бы в оперативку грузить эти файлы, а как нибудь через IO стримы

Comment: 1. Файлы считываются как битовые последовательности и отправлять в бд в таком виде, либо конвертировать в base64. блобы обычно допускают размеры до 2-4гб в каждое значение. 2. SQL все равно должен сконвертироваться в строку - в любом случае файл будет какое-то время в оперативе. Если хочется использовать именно стримы, думаю можно что-то придумать с хранимками. В любом случае, блобы обычно выделяют в отдельную неиндексируемую таблицу, так что по вопросу заливки самих файлов есть определенная свободна для творчества. Может подобный способ передачи фалов поддерживает используемый клиент?

Comment: в принципе blob можно попробовать, спасибо. поддерживает ли клиент стримы это еще надо выяснить